# I am trying to read a .strings file in plist version. I have <key> and <string>. I am not sure how to read these inputs in my javascript code.

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I already have a javascript code where I type a string and find what is expected in my predictive cell and tap on it. Very simple and working fine. However now I have given a plist data which I am not sure how to read it and use it in my code.

Here is an example of the plist that was provided to me:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Animal</key>
    <string>cat | dog | chicken | cow</string>
    <key>Fruits</key>
    <string>apple | cherries | kiwi</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So first how do I read each section? I understand that when you type cat, expected result would be animal according to this plist. So my question is how to do following:

I want to read the  and assign it to a value to be used later
I also need to read  and assign in to an array

example:

```
var inputStringArray = ["cat","dog","chicken","cow"];
var expectedInput = "Animal";
```

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear to me... You are asking how to parse a `plist` file in JavaScript? Could you post some code you developed to do this task? We can start from that.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to this. I think I may be asking how to parse a plist.

Comment: I am using UIAutomation from xcode to test an app. 
                                                                                                    
var inputStringArray = ["cat","dog","chicken","cow"];
var expectedInput = "Animal"; 
var updatedArray = [];
//updatedArray have its own function and it updates it 

          for( var j=0; j<inputStringArray.length; j++){
        typeString(inputStringArray[j];
              if (updatedArray.indexOf(expectedInput) >= 0) {
               tap(expectedinput);
                   Pass;
             }
         }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "plist" format is an XML so you can parse a plist as any other XML in JavaScript using a `DOMParser`:

```js
// Code goes here

var plistString = '<plist version="1.0"><dict><key>Animal</key><string>cat | dog | chicken | cow</string><key>Fruits</key><string>apple | cherries | kiwi</string></dict></plist>';

var parser = new DOMParser()
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(plistString, "text/xml");

var dictEl = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('dict')[0];
var keyAndValues = dictEl.childNodes;

for(var i = 0; i < keyAndValues.length; i++) {
  var el  = keyAndValues[i];
  console.log(el.nodeName, '-', el.textContent);
}
```

You create a `DOMParser` and parse your plist with `parseFromString()` method.

The object `xmlDoc` contains a DOM with the parsed XML and you can navigate it to get evert node you need. In the example above a loop over the key/value objects inside `<dict>` element and print them. Running the code above, you should see in console the following lines:

```
key - Animal
string - cat | dog | chicken | cow
key - Fruits
string - apple | cherries | kiwi
```